# Academic Study: Request to Take Part in University of Michigan Research Project on the Use of Parenting Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, survey

My name is Tawfiq Ammari. I am a PhD student at the University of Michigan, Ann Arbor. I study the use of social media by parents. Some of the research I work on with my adviser, Sarita Schoenebeck can be found [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~tawfiqam/Pubs.html).

We are currently working a study ([link here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~tawfiqam/SEParenting.html)) studying the use of parenting stack exchange. It would be great if we could interview as many of you as possible.

This research has been approved by University of Michigan's Institutional Review Board (#HUM 00103580). The research is supported by funding from the University of Michigan School of Information and the National Science Foundation.

Some details of the study:

```
Are you a parent?
Are you 18 years old or older?
Is your child under the age of 18?
Do you regularly use stack exchange to discuss parenting issues?
```

Participate in a research study at the University of Michigan! We want to learn about how you use Parenting Stack Exchange. Your participation will help us to better understand the lives of parents online today.

If you decide to participate, we will ask you to do an interview with our research team. The interview will take about 30-60 minutes of your time. The interview can be conducted in person or over the telephone or Skype. Participating in any of our studies is completely voluntary. Even if you decide to participate now, you may change your mind and stop at any time.

For more information, please contact Tawfiq Ammari by email at

> tawfiqam@umich.edu

or Dr. Sarita Yardi Schoenebeck, Ph.D by email at

> yardi@umich.edu

.

Comment: I suspect the answer "post in meta" was meant to convey: "post your request for folks to participate in the survey in meta" not "post your question about if you can post a request to take the survey in meta".

Comment: in other words, I think you should be asking folks to participate in the survey here, not asking if you can. :)

Comment: @cabbey, thanks! I will post a request to take part in the survey. Hope you will take part in it as well!

Comment: I'd be interested to find out how many parents have an extra hour to spare for a research interview!

Comment: @CreationEdge doesn't take an hour all the time, we always attempt to accommodate interviewees. The interview could take closer to 30 minutes. In addition, we can do this in parts and you can simply stop the interview and decline to continue if you think it is taking too long.

Comment: Personally, I'd be more than happy to take a web survey, but unfortunately would not be able to participate in an interview.

Comment: I have 3 kids under 18 and like CreationEdge I can do web surveys easily, but trying to fit in a 30 minute call is next to impossible. It took me nearly 2 months to change my mortgage because there was no time window to go and see the bank, and getting a doctor appointment almost never happens...

Comment: "to better understand the lives of parents online today" - I hate to tell a researcher how to do their job, but given a relatively small AND largely self-selected user base of the site - multiplied to selection bias of people taking survey - would any results have any meaning whatsoever?